# How to make a df of unique values from another df columns?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to making a df from only unique values from another df. This is my idea

```
columns = df.columns
df_uniquevalues = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(columns)):
    df_uniquevalues[columns[i]] = df[columns[i]].unique()
    i += 1
```

My idea is extracting unique values by a for cycle. Hope you understand. But the error occurs for this reason "Length of values does no match length of index".

Have you a better idea?
Or, just the way that I can add columns without the index problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe you could use `drop_duplicates()` on each series

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by "unique values", as there are several options to what you meant: whole row unique? only one value is unique?

Anyway, pandas' [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) does exactly what you are asking for. Another option is use [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which receives an numpy array (dataframe is also possible) and returns only unique values.

Comment: Thank you Roim!
I just was refering to unique values of every column.
But with this both answers I'm getting. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`df_uniquevalues = df.drop_duplicates()`

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) discussing the various argument options.

In general looping isn't the way to go with Pandas. There is almost always a vectorized version of the operation you are looking for.